# Beautiful Soup 4 HTML Documents Directory

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working with this Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os
import re

def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\6930p\FLO'S DATEIEN\Master FAU\Sommersemester 2016\02_Masterarbeit\04_Testumgebung\01_Probedateien für Analyseaspekt\Independent Auditors Report")
    for file in glob.glob('*.html'):
        with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f:
            contents = f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
            results = [item for item in soup.findAll("ix:nonfraction") if re.match("^[^:]:AuditFeesExpenses", item['name'])]
            print(results)
                #print(file, end="| ")
                #print(item['name'], end="| ")
                #print(item.get_text())
trade_spider()
```

I am trying to parse multiple HTML documents in a certain directory on my computer with BS4. My aim is to find tags starting with "ix:NonFraction...." containing a name attribute that can have several expressions before 'AuditFeesExpenses' like name="aurep:AuditFeesExpenses, name=bus:AuditFeesExpenses" etc.(that's why I am using a RegEx). So, if BS4 has found that particular tag, I would like to extract the text out of it with soup.get_text(Value).

Anyone an idea what I have missed?

UPDATE: 
An example tag would be:

```
    <td style=" width:12.50%; text-align:right; " class="ta_60">
<ix:nonFraction contextRef="ThirdPartyAgentsHypercube_FY_31_12_2012_Set1"
 name="ns19:AuditFeesExpenses" unitRef="GBP" decimals="0"
 format="ixt2:numdotdecimal" scale="0" xmlns:ix="http://www.xbrl.org
/2008/inlineXBRL">3,600</ix:nonFraction></td>
```

Normally this tag appears in ONE line, for clarity reasons i inserted a few newlines!

My final Code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os
import re

def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\6930p\FLO'S DATEIEN\Master FAU\Sommersemester 2016\02_Masterarbeit\04_Testumgebung\01_Probedateien für Analyseaspekt\Independent Auditors Report")
    for file in glob.glob('*.html'):
        with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f:
            contents = f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
            for item in soup.findAll("ix:nonfraction"):
                if re.match(".*AuditFeesExpenses", item['name']):
                    print(file, end="| ")
                    print(item['name'], end="| ")
                    print(item.get_text())
trade_spider()
```

and gives me this output:

Prod224_0010_00079350_20140331.html| uk-aurep:AuditFeesExpenses| 2,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findAll()` function has `name` as its first parameter. When you call

```
`soup.findAll('ix:NonFraction', name=re.compile("^[^:]:AuditFeesExpenses"))`,
```

you are effectively  calling `soup` with the parameter `name=ix:NonFraction` **AND** `name=re.compile("^[^:]:AuditFeesExpenses")`. Of course, we can only set `name` equal to one of those two inputs, giving the error.

The error message shows `find_all()` instead of `findAll()`. From the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), we see that `findAll` is the old method name of `find_all`. The `find_all` method should be used.

The confusion may be coming from the attribute `name`. It is important to differentiate between the BeautifulSoup attribute `name` and the html attribute `name`. To demonstrate, I assume that a tag has this format:

```
<body>
    <ix:NonFraction name="AuditFeesExpenses">stuff<ix:NonFraction>
</body>
```

We can find all `<ix:NonFraction>` tags with `soup.find_all("ix:nonfraction")`. That gives the following list containing the results:

```
[<ix:NonFraction name="AuditFeesExpenses">stuff<ix:NonFraction>]
```

Iterate through this one-item list to see the two **different** name attributes. First, we access the BeautifulSoup name attribute as an attribute of the object:

```
for item in soup.find_all("ix:nonfraction"):
    print(item.name)

Out: 'ix:nonfraction'
```

To see the html name attribute, access `name` as a dictionary key:

```
for item in soup.find_all("ix:nonfraction"):
    print(item['name'])

Out: 'AuditFeesExpenses'
```

Join both of the searches together to narrow down the results:

```
results = [item for item in soup.find_all("ix:nonfraction") if re.match("^[^:]:AuditFeesExpenses", item['name'])

Out: [<ix:nonfraction name="ns19:AuditFeesExpenses">3,600</ix:nonfraction>]
```

Or, if we want to get the text of each match:

```
results = [item.get_text() for item in soup.find_all("ix:nonfraction") if re.match("^[^:]:AuditFeesExpenses", item['name'])

Out: [3,600]
```

Suggested code for complete output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os

def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Independent Auditors Report")
    for file in glob.glob('*.html'):
        with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f:
            contents = f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
            for item in soup.findAll("ix:nonfraction"):
                if re.match("^[^:]:AuditFeesExpenses", item['name'])
                    print(file, end="| ")
                    print(item['name'], end="| ")
                    print(item.get_text())
trade_spider()
```

Comment: I updated my question so that you can see an example tag that i am trying to use for my code

Comment: Updated answer. I think the problem stems from 2 different `name` attributes. The final solution may require 2 steps: get all `NonFraction` tags, then filter to get all `AuditFeesExpenses` names.

Comment: This works almost perfect, but python prints now every NonFraction-Tag-Name in the document (~100-200 for each document). Is there any chance to filter only for the "AuditFeesExpenses" and in the same time tell Python to gather the text between the tags >3,600<. If I could solve this issue the code would work perfectly!

Comment: I edited your answer with an example of my current output.

Comment: Update OP. I posted my code and the result I get... However I think I am missing something as I don't get any values?!

Comment: You'll have to debug the regex to match exactly what you want. Start with the line `results = [item for item in soup.findAll('ix:nonfraction')]`. Then try different regexes in `re.match` to get what you need. A good site for that is here: http://pythex.org/ If you need further help with the regex, I'd recommend asking a new question with your results up to that point.

Comment: Alright, so the Code itself should work properly?
I also edited your answer. When using my code without your latest answer I get the output in a way that i want it to be and i would like to keep that format. Is there any chance of another way to filter my output without giving up my current format?

Comment: As I think my main question has been solved I will accept the answer, you have been really helpful for my problem! Appreciate it!
I would be glad if you could have a last look at my update on your answer. After that I should be fine :)

Comment: One last thing: Is the RegEx used for the whole Tag to find my name attribute and inside this my desired wording or only inside the name attribute itself (name="...")?

Comment: If you do `re.match("^[^:]:AuditFeesExpenses", item['name'])` it will search only through the name=... attribute of item.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to alter the RegEx a bit that it works but now I get what I want!

Comment: Do you have an idea how to get my Output written into a .txt file with every match in a new line?

Comment: Sure, but that's a good opportunity for a new question. On StackOverflow, we try to keep each question to one particular problem. This question will help other users who have the `name` attribute error, but they may have different output/processing requirements.

Comment: As you had been a very good problem solver an this issue, I would be glad if you could have a glance at my new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172980/open-every-file-subfolder-in-directory-and-print-results-to-txt-file

Comment: `find_all` is what should be used, `findAll` is the old method name