# Open every file/subfolder in directory and print results to .txt file

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, pycharm, subdirectory

At the moment I am working with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os
import re
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()

def trade_spider():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\6930p\FLO'S DATEIEN\Master FAU\Sommersemester 2016\02_Masterarbeit\04_Testumgebung\01_Probedateien für Analyseaspekt\Independent Auditors Report")
    with stdout2file("output.txt"):
        for file in glob.iglob('**/*.html', recursive=True):
            with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f:
                contents = f.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
                for item in soup.findAll("ix:nonfraction"):
                    if re.match(".*AuditFeesExpenses", item['name']):
                        print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")
                        print(item['name'], end="| ")
                        print(item.get_text())
trade_spider()
```

So far this works perfectly. But now I am stucked with another issue. If I search within a folder which has no subfolders but only files this works without problems. However if i try to run this code on a folder that has subfolders it doesn't work (it prints nothing!). 
Furthermore I would like to get my results print into a .txt file without having the whole path in it. The result should be like:

```
Filename.html| RegEX Match| HTML text
```

I do get this result already, but only in PyCharm and not in a seperate .txt file.

To sum up, I do have 2 questions:

1. How can I also walk through subfolders in my defined Directory?
   -> would os.walk() be an option for that?
2. How can I print my results into a .txt file?
   -> would sys.stdout work on that?

Any help appreciated on this issue!

UPDATE:
It only prints the first results of the first file into my "outout.txt" file (at least I think it is the first as it is the last file in my only subfolder and recursive=true is activated). Any idea why it is not looping through all the other files?

UPDATE_2: Question resolved! Final Code can be seen above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For walking in subdirectories, there are two options:

1. Use `**` with glob and the argument `recursive=True` (`glob.glob('**/*.html')`). This only works in Python 3.5+. I would also recommend using `glob.iglob` instead of `glob.glob` if the directory tree is large.
2. Use `os.walk` and check the filenames (whether they end in `".html"`) manually or with `fnmatch.filter`.

---

Regarding the printing into a file, there are again several ways:

1. Just execute the script and redirect stdout, i.e. `python3 myscript.py >myfile.txt`
2. Replace calls to `print` with a call to the `.write()` method of a file object in write mode`.
3. Keep using print, but give it the argument `file=myfile` where `myfile` is again a writable file object.

**edit:** Maybe the most unobstrusive method would be the following. First, include this somewhere:

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout2file(fname):
    import sys
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    f.close()
```

And then, infront of the line in which you loop over the files, add this line (and appropriately indent):

```
with stdout2file("output.txt"):
```

Comment: Alright. The first part with glob.iglob works (almost) perfect. It now finds all files, but it also prints the folder name in front of my desired output. Any chance to search in all subfolders but ONLY print the filename.html as I wrote in my question?

Comment: You will need the full path to open the files, but if you want to only show the filename itself in the call to `print`, you can do `print(file.split(os.path.sep)[-1], end="| ")`.

Comment: What Option would be the most elegant solution without altering my code that much to get my results into a text file? I initially thought that shouldn't be much of a problem...

Comment: Ok, give me a second, I think I have some magic for you there.

Comment: file.split works fine! Thanks! Appreciate your fast response and help on that!

Comment: See my edit for a fourth suggestion on how to put your results in a file.

Comment: Updated my Question. Your suggestion works for one file, after that it seems that it is not looping through all other files?

Comment: Ah, right, because it will open them once for each file. Move that context manager further up (above the loop).

Comment: Awesome! You are genius and by the way you saved my day in this moment :) Appreciated your help on this issue!